# How to get row counts from each tables in a DB based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

i have multiple tables in database ( say *x_db*) and all the tables have a common column having date values( say column *'date'*). **I want to retrieve count of rows for each table in database *x_db* where value of column *'date'* is greater than a specific value.**

Comment: @Larnu - i can't think of query to do this, Need a query to get counts from all tables in db at once. could you please help

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, @Pawan , not is it a help forum; [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) If you haven't been able to write the query what research did you do to try to achieve your goal? What about said research didn't you understand? The only way to achieve this would be with dynamic SQL, and that is not something someone who is new to SQL should be entertaining. Perhaps this is a design flaw or [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Try to rewrite your question and add more info and the scripts you tried before.

Answer (score 0):

**You need dynamic SQL for this. It can be error-prone and difficult to debug.**

- Make sure to pass parameters in via `sp_executesql`
- Anything that can't be passed in make sure to quote with `quotename`

```sql
declare @date datetime = '2021-01-01';

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
(
select string_agg(
N'SELECT ' quotename(schema_name(t.schema_id), '''') + N'.' + quotename(t.name, '''') + N' AS tableName, COUNT(*) AS countRows
FROM ' quotename(schema_name(t.schema_id)) + N'.' + quotename(t.name) + N'
WHERE date > @date
', cast(N'
UNION ALL
' AS nvarchar(max)))
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id and c.name = 'date'
group by t.schema_id, t.name
);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime', @date = @date;
```

Change the type to `datetime2` or whatever if necessary